# Problema para Inserir dados no BD

Tags: java, node.js

Criei um formulário que inseri informações no MySql utilizando o Nodejs, porem o mesmo não esta inserindo nada e nem da nenhum erro no console e nenhum no terminal, segue abaixo o código

```js
admin.js

 module.exports = function(application){
    application.get('/formulario_inclusao_noticia', function(req,res){
        res.render('admin/form_add_noticia');
    });
 
    application.post('/noticias/salvar', function(req,res){
        var noticia = req.body;
 
        var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
        var noticiasModel = application.app.models.noticiasModel(connection); //sugestão informada nos comments
 
        noticiasModel.salvarNoticia(noticia, connection, function(error, result){
            res.redirect('/noticias');
        });
    });
}
noticiasModel.js

module.exports = function(){
 
    this.getNoticias = function(connection, callback){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM noticias', callback);
    }
 
    this.getNoticia = function(connection, callback){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE id_noticia = 2', callback);
    }
 
    this.salvarNoticia = function(noticia, connection, callback){
        connection.query('INSERT INTO noticias SET ?', noticia, callback);
    }
 
    return this;
 
}
```

```html
//form_add_noticia.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>Formulário de cadastro de Notícia</title>
        </head>
    <body>
 
        <h1>Adicionar notícia</h1>
        <br />
 
        <form action="/noticias/salvar" method="post">
            <label>Título</label>
            <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Título da Notícia" />
            <br />
            <label>Notícia</label>
            <textarea id="noticia" name="noticia" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema esta no name do textarea de Noticia

```html
//Antes
<br />
  <label>Notícia</label>
  <textarea id="noticia" name="noticia" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
 <br />
 
 //Depois
 
 <br />
  <label>Notícia</label>
  <textarea id="noticia" name="noticias" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
 <br />
```